# Show multiple images and allow user to post one of them on Facebook Wall using Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Show multiple images and allow user to post one of them on Facebook Friend's Wall by using a Selection.

Still I'm allowing user to post a static image to Facebook Wall, but now I want to allow user to select an image from multiple images and then post to wall.

i am using below **code to post a specific image to wall**, using this code:

```
params.putString("picture", FacebookUtility.STATIC_IMAGE_URL);
```

*Code to post a Static Image*:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            try {
            final long friendId;
            friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
            String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.post_on_wall_title)
                    .setMessage(
                            String.format(getString(R.string.post_on_wall),
                                    name))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();

                                    params.putString("to",
                                            String.valueOf(friendId));
                                    params.putString("caption",
                                            getString(R.string.app_name));
                                    params.putString("description",
                                            getString(R.string.app_desc));
                                    params.putString("link", 
                                            "http://www.google.com");
                                    params.putString("picture", 
                                            FacebookUtility.STATIC_IMAGE_URL);                          
                                    params.putString("name",
                                            getString(R.string.app_action));
                                    FacebookUtility.facebook
                                            .dialog(FriendsList.this,
                                                    "feed",
                                                    params,
                                                    (DialogListener) new PostDialogListener());
                                }

                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class PostDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                showToast("Message posted on the wall.");
            } else {
                showToast("No message posted on the wall.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK posting to friend's wall API's are depricated now. You can post on your own wall and then tag your friend in that image.

Comment: @N-JOY ok so tell me how can i post an image to my fb wall by selecting from multiple images

Comment: There are some predefined ACTIONS available for tagging friend and posting image. Go through FB Documentation.

Comment: @N-JOY please try to understand my point, i want to know how can i select an image from images in android programmaticaly...like above code i am using to post a specific image to wall, using this code:  params.putString("picture", FacebookUtility.STATIC_IMAGE_URL);

Answer (score 0):

What SDK are you using to access Facebook?

You should use the latest SDK (3.0) available from [Facebook directly](https://developers.facebook.com/android/) (or others that incorporate it), and use its Session management and Request classes.

In your case, if you want to post to the user's wall, you can use the [Request.newPhotoUploadRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newUploadPhotoRequest%28Session,%20Bitmap,%20Callback%29) method, which takes a Bitmap. As others have already mentioned, you cannot post to a friend's wall anymore.